# Normal Distribution - help with changing distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

I'm stuck with a question for my statistics class. Suppose a company produces bags containing a certain cereal, and the weight of the bags follow a normal distribution, with mean = 100g and std deviation = 7g. While processing, the weight is tested for each bag and if one of them weights less than 90g, the bag is left out. Last, to make deliveries, a truck is loaded with 50000 bags. What is the probability that the bags will weight more than 5Tn.?

So, I calculated the probability for a bag of weighing less than 90g, which is 0.0764, given the mean and std deviation. However, I think the 50000 bags of the last part of the exercise should have weights that follow a different normal distribution, given that there are no bags of less than 90g, but I dont know how to work this out. Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: To me, Tn is a non-metric weight of $2000$ pounds.  That doesn't seem to make sense here, but I can't find another meaning by Googling.

Comment: Tonne would be 1000kg

Comment: Well, you're right; you need to figure out the mean and standard deviation of the new distribution, and then you can apply the central limit theorem.  Which part are you having trouble with.

Comment: Yes, sorry, by Tn. I was trying to say Tonnes (1000 kgs). I'm having trouble with figuring out the new distribution before applying central limit theorem.

Comment: The proportion of bags omitted is
$$
\Pr(X<90) = \Pr\left( \frac{X-100} 7 < \frac{90-100} 7 \right) = \Pr(Z<-10/7) \approx 0.07656373
$$
where $Z\sim\operatorname N(0,1).$ So the average weight of non-omitted bags satisfies the equation
$$
\begin{align}
100 = {}& 0.07656373\times\text{average weight of omitted bags} \\
& {} + (1-0.07656373)\times \text{average weight of included bags} 
\end{align}
$$
Once you've got the average weight and the variance of weights of included bags, multiply those by $50\,000$ to get...$\qquad$

Comment: ...the mean and variance of the total weight. Treat the total weight as normally distributed by the central limit theorem, even those the weights being summed, after the omission of lighter bags, is no longer normally distributed.

Comment: You need the _conditional_ expected value and variance of a standard normally distributed random variable _given_ that it is more than $-10/7.$ I'm not sure that's easy to get other than by numerical integration. You would also want the conditional variance.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I've been trying to work them out, but so far, I'm not having any luck.  Another possibility to to estimate the conditional mean and variance by simulation and then apply the central limit theorem.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
7^2 = {} & \text{total variance} \\
= {} & 0.07656373\times\text{variance among omitted bags} \\
& {} + (1 - 0.07656373)\times \text{variance among included bags} \\
& {} +  (0.07656373)\times(1-0.07656373)\times(\text{difference})^2 \\ {} \\
& \text{where “difference'' means the difference between} \\
& \text{the average weights of omitted and included bags.}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: BTW note that I wrote $0.07656373$ and not $0.0766$ or the like. It can be hazardous to round more than you have to before the very last step. I suspect got the figure $0.764,$ with $4$ instead of $6,$ as a result of rounding BEFORE you got that number from the table, perhaps from rounding $-10/7$ to $-1.428$ or to $-1.42$ or something like that. Lack of awareness of issues of this kind is one of many respects in which elementary arithmetic is unduly neglected.